# why do we plug i as log(n-1) in merge sort algorithm

Tags: algorithm, mergesort

I have a doubt related to the Mathematical proof of merge sort's algorithm. As i see only the proof is Mathematical but the problem is related to Algorithm.

Time complexity of merge sort in worst case, `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n-1`

=> `T(n) = n-1 + 2T(n/2)`   // recursive part always at end to keep it simpler

By plug & chug method:

```
T(n) = n-1 + 2[n/2-1 + 2T(n/4) ]    //plug
     = n-1 + n-2 + 4T(n/4)          //chug
     = n-1 + n-2 + 4[n/4 -1 + 2T(n/8)]    //plug 
     = n-1 + n-2 + n-3 + ....... + n- 2^i-1 + 2^i T(n/2^i) //rounding off
```

**now i have doubt in this step why did he take i as log(n-1)? which gives us an answer:**

```
     =nlogn -n+1
```

Comment: What do you think `i` should be?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan i think should be just n :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the size of the problem `n` decreases, half at a time, `n` becomes the size of base case problem which can be solved in constant time.
In this case `n=1` is the base case as `T(1)` is known to be of order `O(1)`.

In your expansion, the number `i` is how many times `n` has been halved.

Now the question is: when `n` becomes 1 where the recursion stops, what is the value `i` at that point?

That is, how many times `n` can be divided by 2 until it becomes 1?

The answer is `log_2(n)`

So the 'plug and chug' expansion stops at value `i = log_2(n)`

Comment: i got your answer by taking i=log(n)[_2 means base 2 right?] but he has used log(n-1) as i here :(

Comment: Yes, it means log base two. But when you calculate 'Big O' bound, the base of log can be ignored since log of different bases can be converted to each other by a constant multiplication.

Comment: Whats about the other question i is used as log(n-1) here does it means i have to n is divided log(n-1) times untill it becomes 1?

Comment: It's not really about `n` becoming 1. It's about `n` becoming the size that where you know exactly how long the algorithm will take to solve. In the case of merge sort, we know that the time it takes to sort 1 item is constant. That is you can substitute `T(1)` with `O(1)`. In other problem, it might be the case that you know `T(2)` is `O(1)`. In this other case you want stop the expansion with `n = 2`. which might consequently means `n` was halved `log_2(n-1)` times.

Comment: *Sorry I made a mistake in the last statement. `n` halved `log_2(n)-1`  times gives 2. Not `log_2(n-1)` times. .... `log_2(n-1)` is the number of times it takes to divide `n-1` by two to get `1`.